# Field Momentum and Canonical Momentum in the Classical Field Theory

Tags: momentum, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics, classical-field-theory

From the definition of energy-stress tensor,

$$T_\mu^\nu=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(d_\nu \psi)}d_\mu\psi-\mathcal{L}\delta_\mu^\nu$$

the $i$-th component of momentum carried by "field" is expressed as

$$T_i^0=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\dot\psi)}d_i\psi,$$
which is in the form of canonical momentum conjugate to the field variable multiplied by the variation of the field variable along the $i$-th axis.

So far, all of the textbooks I referred to fall into either of categories in justifying the above argument:

(1) It is self-evident to define $T_i^0$ as a canonical momentum from $d_\nu T_\mu^\nu=\partial_\mu\mathcal{L}$.

(2) Argue with the continuous string.

But to me, either of the argument is hard to accept, and some linking argument seems in need. So my questions are as follows.

(1) The dimension analysis shows $T_i^0$ indeed has the dimension of the momentum density. But I don't grasp how come canonical momentum multiplied by $d_i\psi$ gives the $i$-th component of the momentum carried by the field. Could somebody suggest an explanation for this without relying on a specific model such as continuous string?

(2) The physical meaning (or intuition) about the canonical momentum conjugate to the field variable

====

Edit)
To elaborate on my question, the gist should be "how $-T_i^0$, which is a canonical momentum multiplied by $-\frac{d\psi}{dx^\mu}$ can be interpreted as a physical momentum carried by field.

So my question was simply about an intuition residing behind the mathematical formula $\pi\times\left(-\frac{d\psi}{dx^\mu}\right)$. I managed to drive my own answer based on the 1-D example illustrated in Goldstein. If someone finds some error in my intuitive understanding, please provide me a correction.

My understanding is as follows:

Considering an infinitesimal volume $d^Nx^\mu$, the field motion of $\psi$ results in the change of $\psi$ by $\psi(x^\mu)-\psi(x^\mu+dx^\mu)=--\frac{d\psi}{dx^\mu}dx^\mu$ in the $x^\mu$ direction. Therefore, the field momentum in the $x^\mu$ direction is $\pi\times\left(-\frac{d\psi}{dx^\mu}\right)$.

Comment: Continuity eq $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} = 0$ and hence (under some additional conditions at infinity) conservation of $\int T^{0\nu} dV$ follows from the fact that Lagrangian density does not explicitly depend on coordinates, which is the same assumption that is used to prove conservation of 4-momentum. So both values should be related. The fact that they coincide can be demonstrated by a simple example, e.g. a string.

Comment: @xaxa Thanks for your comment. However, my question was how to prove that they coincide without relying on any specific example...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "prove" that they coincide. But let me remark that the formula of the stress-energy tensor you have written above is not really a random definition, but rather it is the consequence of Noether's theorem using the space-time translations and since we know that energy-momentum conservation follows from space-time translation, we know that the stress-energy tensor describes energy and momentum.

Comment: I’m not sure it’s a strict proof in mathematical sense, but basically, they are both obtained by the same method (Noether’s theorem as @G. Blaickner pointed out) from the same value (Lagrange function/Lagrangian density of this very Lagrange function), so they should coincide up to a proportionality coefficient. That’s because in Noether’s theorem you have $something = 0$, so common coefficient can’t be defined.

Comment: Now you can consider some example using both Lagrange function and Lagrangian density, and then choose this coefficient such that they coincide exactly

Comment: @JonginnYun : the question how canonical momentum (density) and field momentum (aka physical momentum density) are exactly related, including what their dimensions are, is nicely addressed in this [script](https://www.astrophys-neunhof.de/mtlg/fieldtheory.pdf) on p. 59.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Comment: @xaxa (+G. Blaickner): Thanks for your reply. I think I am not fully understanding them at the definition level. I'll elaborate on my question if I still get confused even after the thorough study of the field theory.